# labeling vertices in a graph to minimize distance between adjacent vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We have a regular graph $G$ of degree $m$  on $n$ vertices and we label each of its vertices with the number $1$ through $n$. What can we say about the maximum difference between the numbers of two adjacent vertices. What is the maximum and minimum, what is the minimum for a specific graph?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I believe the quantity you are asking about is known as [graph bandwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth). Perhaps the references on that wiki page will be helpful?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want, In fact I thought of this because of this question: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2188644&sid=5a886f52b1c0e36aafd4526c9624df38#p2188644